# MongoDB index for limit number of documents of each user in the same collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to save documents into a collection.
Each user has 5 documents at max.

```
{uid: 1, ad_id: 1}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 2}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 3}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 4}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 5}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 6}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 7}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 8}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 9}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 10}
```

Now we have a new doc `{uid: 1, ad_id: 11}`
Because the max number of documents is 5, we delete the oldest one. 
The collection becomes this:

```
{uid: 1, ad_id: 11}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 1}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 2}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 3}
{uid: 1, ad_id: 4}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 6}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 7}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 8}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 9}
{uid: 2, ad_id: 10}
```

Now I check the number in code. Is there any index that mongo could do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont thinks so, You'll have to controll it on your application code.

You could limit just to one record with unique indexes but not to N documents. Besides, new saves will fail instead of overwritting the previous one.

Comment: Thanks.  I took a interview recently. The interviewer said there's a index which could handle this. I did some research but I couldn't figure it out. The interviewer might talk a different scenario with mine. :(.